# Unity's 2D sprite editor doesn't allow placing bones in multiple sprites?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, animator

Hello Stack OverFlow friends,

Please, sorry my pour english, and sorry for my newbie behavior in Unity, but I'll try to be as clear as possible:

I'm trying to create a **2D** **animation** with **bones**, through unity's **own sprite editor** where everything goes well if I **don't Slice the image**... the bones act correctly on the different parts of the body.
[image]

But... I need this image in sprites....
because each part will be able to be changed in the game later..

soo, from that point forward, the bones no longer act on the other sprites!
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

unity ver. = 2022.3.7f1 and 2023.1.7f1

Comment: I confess I thought this was possible but.. that the image was made say in photoshop in layers so the arms/legs etc were layers but in the right place and you could then draw all the bones and animate ...  But its not something ive had to look into